# Flex: rule of thumb for when to re-download data versus load it from cache?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm new to Flex. Let's say we have a web application that needs to download several series of data (several thousand numbers) used by one screen.

When the user leaves that screen and later returns to it (in the same session; that is, the user hasn't logged out then logged back in), should the application fetch the original downloaded data from cache or simply download it again?

What are pros and cons of each and are there any general rules of thumb to follow when it comes to re-downloading data (e.g. again) versus simply getting it from cache? The goal would be to minimize user's wait time as long as there's no drawback. Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to get it from cache than to get it from the server (as long as the data won't be stale).  Getting it from cache will free up resources on
1. the user's computer
2. your server
3. the internet

If there is a threat that the data may be stale you can conditionally send new data to the user if the last time the data was modified is more recent than when the user got the data.

Flash is slow enough as it is, don't make it slower.

Comment: Thank you Boundless. So re-downloading it again makes sense if the data could potentially be stale. Otherwise, pull it from cache. That sounds like one good rule of thumb.

Comment: @ggkmath This is correct... but also if you are talking about a sizable amount of data, even if it could be stale it is better to do a simple check to see if it really is stale, then to request new data.  You can do this by having the user record the date/time that they got the data.  Then when they need to check if the data is stale they send the server the date.  The server will either send back a notice that the data is still valid, or send back the updated data.  Does this make sense?